# nested sampling of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random, dplyr, sample

In data.frame `p` below, there are `757` unique district names (`dname`) & `5210` unique school names (`sname`).

I was wondering how to sample 126 `sname`s (schools) from 40 `dname`s (districts) in R?

So, in the final sample (say `X`), `dim(table(X$dname, X$sname))` must return: `> [1] 40 126`

In a sense, this is `multi-stage sampling`, so I'm open to any packages.

```
p <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/a.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try the code below for this sort of `multi-stage sampling`

```
unq_dname <- unique(p$dname)
repeat {
  out <- subset(p, dname %in% sample(unq_dname, 40))
  if (length(unique(out$sname)) == 126) break
}
```

and you can check the dimensions via

```
dim(with(out,table(dname,sname)))
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your feedback! It seems the the code should jump out of the loop if there are `126` rows as the output. I will double check if I missed something...

Comment: @akrun It seems OP has the cases that some of the single `sname` falls into multiple `dname`s. I updated my code regarding the condition of `break`